# VS Xamarin 'couldn't connect to Mac.local'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I can SSH into my Mac (VMWare), I can ping it etc, all fine. But Xamarin won't connect, if I type incorrect credentials it notifies me so but typing correct ones just states 'Couldn't connect to Mac.local. Please try again.'.

Troubleshooting guide did not solve this.

VS is on 'Stable' update channel. Xamarin Studio is on 'Stable' channel but not updated as it keeps saying 'packages failed to install'. Could this be why?

Log of update:

> 2016-10-10 12:50:44.589 Xamarin Update[888:13432] Reading index file
>   2016-10-10 12:50:44.591 Xamarin Update[888:13432] Loaded 1 updates
>   from index file 2016-10-10 12:50:44.591 Xamarin Update[888:13432]
>   Requesting root authorization for  2016-10-10 12:50:47.028
>   Xamarin Update[888:13432] Acquired root authorization 2016-10-10
>   12:50:47.036 Xamarin Update[888:13550] Installing update 1 of 1
>   2016-10-10 12:50:47.037 Xamarin Update[888:13550] Installing package
>   '/Users/xamarin/Library/Caches/XamarinStudio-6.0/TempDownload/MonoFramework-MDK-4.6.1.5.macos10.xamarin.universal.pkg'
>   2016-10-10 12:50:47.037 Xamarin Update[888:13550] /usr/sbin/installer
>   -pkg '/Users/xamarin/Library/Caches/XamarinStudio-6.0/TempDownload/MonoFramework-MDK-4.6.1.5.macos10.xamarin.universal.pkg'
>   -target / -verboseR 2016-10-10 12:50:47.037 Xamarin Update[888:13550] Requesting root authorization for /usr/sbin/installer 2016-10-10
>   12:50:47.039 Xamarin Update[888:13550] Acquired root authorization
>   2016-10-10 12:51:04.861 Xamarin Update[888:13550] ERROR: installer did
>   not indicate successful completion 2016-10-10 12:51:04.862 Xamarin
>   Update[888:13550] Update failed to install 2016-10-10 12:51:04.862
>   Xamarin Update[888:13432] Error Domain=xamarin.updater Code=-1
>   "Package failed to install" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Package
>   failed to install} installer: Package name is Mono Framework
>   installer: Upgrading at base path / installer:PHASE:Preparing for
>   installation… installer:PHASE:Preparing the disk…
>   installer:PHASE:Preparing Mono Framework… installer:PHASE:Waiting for
>   other installations to complete… installer:PHASE:Configuring the
>   installation… installer:PHASE:Writing files…
>   installer:PHASE:Validating packages… installer: The upgrade failed
>   (The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to
>   fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.)

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. Windows and MacOS machine must have the same version of Xamarin installed, otherwise "Xamarin Mac Agent" is not able (in most cases) to connect.
Before trying anything else you should first update Xamarin on your Mac to latest stable version. Personally I would start with deleting installation packages (you have paths in your log) and trying to download it once again.

Comment: I attempted that and it still did not work. My VS was saying it could not load the 'broker'. 

My solution was to make a fresh new Mac OS X VM and then reinstall Xamarin and dependancies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill Xamarin process (Xamarin borker or something similar):

```
kill -9 {Xamarin PID}
```

to display list of processes use :

```
ps aux
```